# JSON.parse localStorage unexpected end of input error

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

This line

```
item = JSON.parse(localStorage["item"]);
```

caused an error in my console showing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` when my localstorage has no value? How do I resolve this issue? I know that empty string is not a valid json.

Comment: because an empty string is not valid json

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks for clarify that, but how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Easy test to see if the string is empty first, if it is dont parse

Comment: @PatrickEvans `localStorage["item"] !== "" ? JSON.parse(localStorage["item"]);` correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(localStorage["item"]){
  item = JSON.parse(localStorage["item"]);
}
```

Comment: It will only assign the variable if the "item" key exists in localStorage. You may want to set item to null, or another value that is safe for your code, in the event the key doesn't exist (a ternary would be a clean way to do it).

Comment: Code without an explanation is rarely helpful.